# How to extend chartjs line charts in ReactJS to show solid and dashed line together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js, linechart

I want to ***draw solid and dotted line together in REACT JS using ChartJS*** something like "https://jsfiddle.net/3gxjfndm/3/". I couldn't understand how can I extend the chart in my react js file as the context (ctx) is hard to get. I understand the basic concept but couldn't implement on my React Component.

Following is my line Chart implementation which is a BAD implementation I believe.

````
import Chart from 'chart.js';

class LineChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.canvasRef = React.createRef();
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myChart = new Chart(this.canvasRef.current, {
        type: 'line',
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
            hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true
            },
            legend:{
                display:false,
            },
            scales: {
                x: {
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Month'
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Value'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        data: {
            labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'],
            datasets: [{
                label: "My First dataset",
                data: [1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4],
                borderColor: '#66f',
                borderDash: [20, 30],
                pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
            },{
                label: "My Dotted dataset",
                data: [null, null, null, null, null, null, 4, 7, 5, 3, 2],
                borderColor: '#66f',
                pointBackgroundColor: "transparent"
            }]
        }
        });
    }


    render() {
        return (
             <div className="chart-section">
                <div className="chart-body">
                    <canvas ref={this.canvasRef} />
                </div>
            </div>
        ) 
    }
}

export default LineChart;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-chartjs-2 https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2 , it implements chart.js for React and you can call it like any regular React component when the options and the datasets are just like in chart.js.

Comment: but it won't solve my problem. I need solid and dashed line together. It's not possible without extend in React-Chartjs-2. I don't know how to extend the charts to make custom charts.

Comment: In a new version of chartjs there is plugins support and you can use plugins also with React-chartjs-2 (like here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-example-kuxob?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Inside the plugin functions you get chart object with ctx field - I am not sure if it is good enough.